# How to download a local copy of a site with mathjax with wget?

Tags: wget

I can download a local version of a site using command like:

`wget -p -k -H -E -r -nc --no-parent https://www.example.com`

However, unlike when I locally save a page from firefox via `ctrl + s`, the wget version above doesn't render MathJax.

How can I download files locally such that mathJax parts are rendered properly?

EDIT:

These resides in the  of example page:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.2.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script>documenterBaseURL="."</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.min.js" data-main="assets/documenter.js"></script>

<script src="siteinfo.js"></script>

<script src="../versions.js"></script>

<link href="assets/highlightjs/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="assets/documenter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Which website is it? Could you provide the link? It could have something to do with where the `mathJax` libraries are located. If they are in a folder above the location you are trying to fetch, the recursive `wget` might not pull it.

Comment: Sorry, can't do that due to potential privacy concern, I edited in more details from <head> of the page on the question

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p http://www.website.com
```

If it does not work, you might need a second run of wget to retrieve the missing files from the website using the -i flag to lists all the URL's and match to see if you missed one.

Reference:

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options

Comment: `wget -E -H -k -K -p http://www.website.com` didn't work on the site I was trying to copy locally. I am not sure how to do double pass, I am barely familiar with this tool.